# Dashed lines indicating more rows in a table

Tags: tables

I have a table illustrating a row in a table, like this:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    %caption, label ++
\end{table}
```

How can I best make dashed lines up/down at the top/bottom of the table, to indicate that there are more rows? Desired output will be something like this:

[image]

The dashed lines between cell 1&2 and 2&3 are not strictly necessary.

I know I can achieve this with TikZ but I would like to know if there is a way to do it with the tabular environment or something similar.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thanks I guess? I've used the site (and all of SE) a lot, first question here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you have read the [`booktabs` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and know you should not be using vertical lines anyway, so you could just put `\vdots` in the cells above and below.  For example,

[image: No verts sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}\\
    \midrule
    Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Anyway, given that you wish to persist with vertical lines a relatively simply way to do this is to use `\multicolumn`s to restyle cells and to place `\vdots` at the boundaries:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \multicolumn{1}{@{\vdots}c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{@{\vdots}c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{@{\vdots}c@{\vdots}}{}\\
    \hline
    Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{@{\vdots}c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{@{\vdots}c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{@{\vdots}c@{\vdots}}{}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that there is some misalignment here, which can be overcome by using a version of `\vdots` without width:

```
\newcommand{\narrowvdots}{\hbox to 0pt{\hss\vdots\hss}}
```

You can do this with dashes as follows:

[image: Dashed sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\myvdashes}{\raisebox{1ex}{\oalign{\vrule height 1ex\cr\vrule height
1ex\cr \vrule height 1ex}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \multicolumn{1}{@{\myvdashes}c@{\myvdashes}}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c@{\myvdashes}}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c@{\myvdashes}}{}\\
    \hline
    Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{@{\myvdashes}c@{\myvdashes}}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c@{\myvdashes}}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c@{\myvdashes}}{}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the last approach is very neat. I will wait a bit and accept if no one else has a different (better) approach.